# Parking damage-scraped wall or car?

Tags: damage, scratch

I just realized (while taking my car out for the first time in a few days) that my car is pretty badly scratched. I didn’t see it until I was out but I am wondering if this could have happened in the parking lot. I keep it in my apartment buildings garage (it was backed in). To the best of my knowledge, I didn't scratch, scrape or touch a wall. Is it possible to get a scratch like this from another car? It is large red scrapping.[image: Red Scratches Front Drivers Side]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you brushed a car or a car brushed you.

It may clean off with a professional cutting compound but it might have affected your paint layers.